# How to Properly use the ng-model Directive and its Controller in Custom Directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-components

I've created a directive which wraps [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) and I used `ng-model` inside my custom directive tag to pass some json data.

My question is : Do I have to use `ng-model` in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

> I've created a directive which wraps [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) and I used `ng-model` inside my custom directive tag to pass some json data. Do I have to use `ng-model` in this case ?

The [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) instantiates the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). It is a complex directive that enables [form validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) and is the prerequisite for the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). Avoid using `ng-model` as an attribute name unless it is used as intended. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)

For data inputs, simply use [one-way `<` binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

```
<my-tree tree-data="vm.treeData">
</my-tree>
```

```
app.component("myTree", {
     bindings: { treeData: '<' }
     template: `<div>my-tree component</div>`,
     controller: function() {}
})
```

[One-way `<` binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) has been available since v1.5. Only the component that owns the data should modify it, to make it easy to reason about what data is changed, and when.

---

## How to add `ng-model` functionality to a component<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44595910/5535245)</sup>

When implementing `ng-model`, use [one-way `<` binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) for input and use the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) for output:

```
app.component("checkboxComponent", {
    bindings: { ngModel: '<' },
    require: { ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel' },
    template: `
          <input type=checkbox ng-model='$ctrl.ngModel'
                 ng-change="$ctrl.ngModelChange()" />
    `,
    controller: function() {
      this.ngModelChange = () => {
        this.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(this.ngModel);
      };
    }
})
```

The component uses one-way binding for input, and `$setViewValue` for output.
With this method, the `ng-change` works, and the component can be used as a form element:

```
<form name="form1">
     <checkbox-component name="input1" ng-model="vm.formData.input1"
                         ng-change="vm.inp1Change()">
     </checkbox-component>
</form>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide -Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8gcFJwGteJ7BlHPua2yb?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])

.component("checkboxComponent", {
    bindings: { ngModel: '<' },
    require: { ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel' },
    template: `
        <fieldset>
          <h3>Checkbox Component</h3>
          <input type=checkbox ng-model='$ctrl.ngModel'
                 ng-change="$ctrl.ngModelChange()" />
                 Checkbox
        </fieldset>
    `,
    controller: function() {
      this.ngModelChange = () => {
        this.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(this.ngModel);
      };
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <checkbox-component ng-model="value"
                        ng-change="value2=value"> 
    </checkbox-component>
    <fieldset>
      <p>value = {{value}}</p>
      <p>value2 = {{value2}}</p>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
```